# Create subsets of rows and correspond columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as example below, and want to create some copies of rows according to the quantity of B1-B4. Futher more, fill in the alphabet in new correspond columns by turns.

raw dataframe:

```
       B1   B2   B3  B4
 0     1C 
 1     3A   1A
 2    41A  28A   3A 
 3    42A  41A  28A  3A
```

### Target output:

```
       B1   B2   B3  B4  B1_u  B2_u  B3_u  B4_u
 0     1C                   C
```

Explanation:
`row 0`: only have 1 value at `B1`, so there's just one output(the `C` of `1C`) fill in the correspond column `B1_u`

```
       B1   B2   B3  B4  B1_u  B2_u  B3_u  B4_u
 1     3A   1A              A     
 2     3A   1A                    A
```

Explanation:
`row 1`: here's 2 value(`3A`, `1A`), so extend 2 rows, and fill in (the `A` of `3A` & `1A`) the correspond columns `B1_u`, `B2_u` by turns

and etc.

```
       B1   B2   B3  B4  B1_u  B2_u  B3_u  B4_u
 3    41A  28A   3A         A    
 4    41A  28A   3A               A     
 5    41A  28A   3A                     A

       B1   B2   B3  B4  B1_u  B2_u  B3_u  B4_u
 6    42A  41A  28A  3A     A          
 7    42A  41A  28A  3A           A    
 8    42A  41A  28A  3A                 A   
 9    42A  41A  28A  3A                       A
```

Comment: Could you provide some more insight into the rules that determine the output you want? It wasn't obvious to me what these are. Have you attempted to generate the output you want? If so please post your attempts so far.

Comment: Hi @smj, I've updated my question more detail. Wish this will be more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

**IIUC:** Here is a solution:

First lets create the data-set required for this problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
#Code to generate data-set - not explained
df = pd.DataFrame(np.tril(np.random.randint(1, 100, (10,10))), columns=[f'B{x}' for x in range(1, 11)])
df = df.applymap(str)
df = df.replace('0', '')
pp = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(26)*1000., size=1)[0]
cl = np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_uppercase), size=(10), p=pp)
for x in range(0, len(df)):
    for y in range(0, x + 1):
        df.iloc[x, y] = f'{df.iloc[x, y]}{cl[x]}'
#Solution code
#Create a dataframe to store the output from the columns of input dataframe and its index
dfo = pd.DataFrame(columns=[f'{x}_u' for x in df.columns], index=df.index)
#Count non empty values in all the rows
vc = df.apply(lambda x: np.count_nonzero(x), axis=1)
#NOTE: If you have a row that can have more than one attribute then you need to revisit your problem
#Irrespective how the data-set was generated the following code shall work
#Lets populate the output dataframe as required by running nested for loops
for i, v in enumerate(vc):
    for j in range(0, v):
        dfo.iloc[i, j] = list(df.iloc[i, j])[-1]

result = df.join(dfo)
```

**This is how the output will be:**

[image]